# Windows Batch File calling Oracle PL/SQL block- Format Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file

I have a DB.bat file which holds PL/SQL block as below. The problem here i'm facing is the extract exported to csv has text format. I need to have it in a tabular structure. Please guide me how to achieve the tabular format in csv after spool.

c:\desktop\DB.bat:

```
call sqlplus ID/pwd@db @c:\desktop\code.sql
```

c:\desktop\code.sql:

```
set head off
set feed off
set pagesize 0
spool c:\desktop\DB.csv
--PL/SQL Block ---
spool off
set head on
set feed 6
quit
```

Comment: Please add your PL/SQL code, sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking, but... In order to output info from a PL/SQL block to a spool file, you need two things: `set serveroutput on` in your sql*plus script, and sending your info to `dbms_output.put_line` in your PL/SQL block. Here's an example:

```
set head off
set feed off
set pagesize 0
set serveroutput on
spool c:\desktop\DB.csv
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('test1,test2,test3');
end;
/
spool off
```

If by "PL/SQL block" you just mean a plain SQL query, then Olafur's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

tabular as in:

**Fixed column width?**

```
lpad(col1,*100) || lpad(col2,*100) || lpad(col3,*100) || etc..
```

where *100 is more than the maximum text size per that column

**Delimited?**

```
col1 || chr(9) || col2 || chr(9) || col3 || etc...
```

Where chr(9) is Tab and can be anything. || '|' || for pipe, || ',' || for comma, etc..

Tabular formats in text files, csv or "comma separated files" come in all kinds of flavor, what are you looking for?

Regards
Olafur

```
ps, tab delimited example

set serveroutput on
begin
  for i in (select tablespace_name || chr(9) || table_name || chr(9) || to_char(last_analyzed, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as line from user_tables order by table_name) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(i.line);
  end loop;
end;
set serveroutput off
```

Comment: Tabular what I meant was data into rows and columns ( Similar to a database table output structure ) where each value is stored in each cell

Comment: Your piping into a text file, i.e. .csv file (via spool). You can't have a structured rows/columns without defining how they should be structured